# Using Anaconda in Linux (on a Chromebook)

Tags: linux, anaconda, spyder, chromebook

So I have a Chromebook, trying to get Anaconda working on it.  I put it in developer mode, installed Crouton, ran `sudo startxfce4`, installed the Linux distribution of Anaconda, and updated the PATH.  I've verified that running `conda update` worked and updated, and when I execute `env` it prints, among many other things, `PWD=/home/muhname/anaconda3/bin` which I think verifies that the PATH is correct.  Still when I execute `spyder` it tells me the command is not recognized, yet that seems to be what I'm supposed to do to get Spyder to open.  Any thoughts about what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At the $ prompt, enter `which spyder`, what do you see?
If you are having trouble with Crouton, consider installing dual-boot Linux. I run Python on a Ubuntu/ChromeOS dual-boot ARM chromebook, [Ubuntu dual boot](https://github.com/com-py/Hibuntu). If yours is x86 based, consider chrx.org or galliumOS.